# Javascript accessing multidimensional Array without knowing all keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a little experience in Javascript and usually I found solution to my problems just by searching here or with Google
But this time, I feel that I took the wrong path

I have build an Object (multidimensional associative array) like this :
state["a"]["b"]["c"] = "idle";

If I know "a" and "c" but not "b", can I change the value "idle" , without looping through each keys ?
taking into account that "c" is unique in the whole object

Something like :
state["a"][*]["c"] = "busy";

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: no you can not, and if you don't know the keys, how can you assure they are to be unique? you have to write a tree parser most likely using recursion. depending on what environment/browser you are to support you can use Object.keys or "for in" loop

Comment: So you know: there are no "multidimensional" structures in JS. They are simply nested objects/arrays.

Comment: I know that key is unique as I build the object using some data from which is value can't exist twice ! Just in the current function "b" isn't used nor known ... Too bad, I will loop with Object.keys ... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "c" only exists in one place as you've stated, then you'll need to loop through the items in the second dimension looking for the one that has a third dimension with an index of "c".

Comment: This is exactly what I would like to avoid :-)